# Google Map Website url params to go from A to B using waypoints

Tags: google-maps, url

Just a little post because I didn't found what i want on the internet so i hope someone will have the response to my answer.

I try to open Google Maps via url i.e. `maps.google.com?parameters=value`
but i still can't find how to tell in the url to go from A to B through some waypoints

Thanks for answering !

Answer (score 1):

Use the [embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/): 
[Directions mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide#directions_mode)

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
  ?key=YOUR_API_KEY
  &origin=Oslo+Norway
  &destination=Telemark+Norway
  &avoid=tolls|highways
```

> The following URL parameters are required:
>
> **origin** defines the starting point from which to display directions. The value can be either a place name, address or place ID. The string should be URL-escaped, so an address such as "City Hall, New York, NY" should be converted to City+Hall,New+York,NY. (The Google Maps Embed API supports both + and %20 when escaping spaces.) Place IDs should be prefixed with place_id:.
>
> **destination** defines the end point of the directions.
>
> The following URL parameters are optional:
>
> **waypoints** specifies one or more intermediary places to route directions through between the origin and destination. Multiple waypoints can be specified by using the pipe character (|) to separate places (e.g. Berlin,Germany|Paris,France). You can specify up to 20 waypoints. Each waypoint can be either a place name, address or place ID.

[example (using coordinates)](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_directions_waypoints.html)

```
<iframe width="100%" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions
 ?key=yourAPIkey
 &origin=58.2835809,12.269723200000044
 &destination=58.03126090000001,12.80391750000001
 &waypoints=58.03126090000001,12.803917500000011|58.2583346,12.95071710000002|58.2835809,12.269723200000044"
 allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: in my use case, i just need to redirect the user on the google map website with some parameters i don't need to display it into an iframe :(

Comment: There is no documented way to do that.